# From python, can I interact with any HID device?

Tags: usb

Can I interact with essentially any HID device from a Pi? (displays, controllers, etc) ?

If so, is there a python example out there that shows reading from hid?

Comment: Did you have something to add to this?

Comment: @Jivings  -- yes, thx, done!

Comment: Please do not `Thanks` In your question! You should know by now that upvoting is thanking people. I see answers but no upvotes so you are not grateful for the help? Please read the FAQ to get up to speed with how Q&A works. Besides this is off-topic as it has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi -1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the python wrapper for libusb **PYUSB** to programmatically read and write to a HID device from python.

Please look at my answer on this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/usb-hid-device-only-firing-1-event) for some ideas on how to achieve this.The library is fairly easy to use.There is also a good beginner tutorial on the [website](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/).

Please note that pyUsb can only help getting data in and out of the HID device.Decoding the data is another story.You might need to use usb loggers to decode the data.

Comment: Just for the record you deserve a +1 - The op thinks otherwise :(